# Mysql Between and One Must Have Condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, mysql-error-1064, between

I did made some changes, Here is the new table and query. 
But still iam getting wrong results

http://prntscr.com/7ofyc8

Here is my query and results
/*edit*/

The problem is, I should get only one result and it has PriceCarId 2

I tryed something but different, but it didnt work too

http://prntscr.com/7og5lb

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT PriceCarId FROM Prices WHERE (PriceDate BETWEEN '05/07/2015' AND '07/07/2015') AND (PriceCarStatu=0)



I tryed this, its give me two results, but its should be one result

Comment: seems you have taken `PriceDate` as varchar, why ?? you need to change data type for `PriceDate` to `date`

Comment: alternatively, you can `cast` your `PriceDate` field as `date` to compare

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, You should change `PriceDate` datatype to `date`, Alternatively you may use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), see example below:

```
SELECT * FROM Prices 
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(PriceDate, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2015-07-05' AND '2015-07-07') AND PriceCarStatu = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but its still giving me wrong result, Can you check new images on first post ? I changed

Comment: what are you getting ? edit your question with present results and expectations!

Comment: That is cause, `PriceDate` is type of varchar (I guess)

Comment: I changed it to int, but its still giving me PriceCarId 1 and 2, I should see only PriceCarId 2